# Laravel :doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel-5

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'product_name' doesn't have a default value

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\product;

class productController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['title'] = "index page";
        return view('product.index', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['title'] = "create page";
        return view('product.create', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        //    $product=new product();  
        //    $product->product_name=$data['pro_name'];  /
        //    $product->description=$data['description'];
        //    $product->Starting_Date_and_Time=$data['SDAT'];
        //    $product->Ending_Date_and_Time=$data['EDAT'];
        //    $product->save();
        $product = product::create($data);   
        dd($product);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('product.edit');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return 'product delete';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `$data = $request->all();` if you have `$data['pro_name']`; it doesn't know to map that to `product_name`. Use the manual syntax you've commented out, or change `$data['pro_name']` to `$data['product_name']`. Same with `SDAT` and `EDAT`; those don't map to `Starting_Date_and_Time` and `Ending_Date_and_Time`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.